# Google Map Javascript fails in local Tomcat 8.0.24

Tags: tomcat8

I am attempting to open an HTML page containing Google Maps JavaScript API.

This works fine if I open the HTML directly from the filing system (Microsoft Edge, IE11, Google Chrome), displaying the required map and a few experimental lines.

My ultimate aim is to launch the Google Map page via a JSP called from a Java Applet.

I attempted to launch the originally working HTML page from an Applet launched via a local Tomcat using IE11. This displayed the required map but without the experimental lines and it was clear that Google Maps had crashed, as it did not respond to any events.

I also launched the same HTML page directly via a newly started IE11 using the local Tomcat website. This did not work either - no big surprise, but worth the experiment.

However, when I launched the same HTML page directly via Microsoft Edge using the local Tomcat website, it worked as expected.

Unfortunately neither Microsoft Edge nor Google Chrome appear to support Java Applets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it. What does the javascript have to do with Tomcat?

Comment: The JavaScript is in the HTML page and is used to create the Google Map. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/  I have no idea why this works via Tomcat in Microsoft Edge, but not IE11.